# Multi website and multi store view with custom url in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, multistore, url-rewrite, base-url

I have a magento 2 installed and configured the following:

1. default website with 1 store view called `us_en`
2. eu website with 1 store view called `eu_en`

When I change base url to store view like `domain_name/us/en` or `domain_name/eu/en` that store view fails to load, even the cms pages located in `http://localhost/about_us` not loading.

I suspect I am missing a step with respect to magento router.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change settings from admin section:

Go to admin->store->configuration->General->Web and in

Url Options setting enable **Add Store Code to Urls** to Yes

Now Clean all cache.

Answer (score -1):

check this guide https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-and-configure-multistore-magento-2/ can help you with your setup.Did you make changes in index.php and .htaccess file?

Comment: No, I have not made any changes to index.php or .htaccess. But I am passing MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE variables through nginx configuration file.

Comment: @AlagunambiWelkin Did you solve it? Having the same struggle right now

Comment: If you're running nginx + php-fpm the MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE from your nginx configuration will arrive in php as REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE and REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_TYPE.  You'll have to solve this in index.php as there is no workaround. However, if you want to run both stores on the same domain you should use the answer provided by @akgola